# Printing out multiple PostgreSQL query statements in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, postgresql

I have just started making my web-system and I have came across a problem with the results printing out. I am selecting a start and end destination from a drop down list. When I press submit this only prints out the end destination tram name and tram times but doesn't print out the start destination tram name and tram times.

I am not sure whether I am printing out the results properly. Should I be printing them out row by row or leave them as an fetched array. My code is the following:

```
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table>\n";
echo "These are the following trams from '$name' to '$name2' ";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "\t<tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
      echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
  echo "</table>\n";

// Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);


 // Closing connection
 pg_close($dbconn);
```

Comment: Make your life beeing much easier by separating markup from logic ;)

Comment: What am I supposed to separate @bub

Comment: done any basic debugging, like running that query separately/outside of PHP and seeing if it returns the proper results in the first place? You're just assuming this is a PHP problem. But php doesn't have any built in "I don't like this guy, let's mess with him and skip some result rows" code. It'll loop on/display everything your query returned, so if you're  missing a result row, then maybe the query isn't producing that row in the first place.

Comment: I have ran the query in my PgAdmin and it works perfectly fine. It brings both set of results for both the start and end destination. My PHP code only prints out the end destination results. I have tried debugging this and seeing what I am doing wrong but not had any luck with this @MarcB